# C++ : Using functions from another project

Tags: c++, visual-studio, linker

I'm getting linking errors in visual studio. There are two projects. One is a static library, the other is an executable. I've pointed the .exe project properties so that it knows where to find the .lib file and library directory. Not quite sure why it still won't detect the functions from that project I'm trying to use. I've also checked to make sure the function signatures matched and that they were implemented.

Any other suggestions I can try?
Also, what does setting project dependencies do exactly? I've tried setting the .exe project to depend on the static lib project, but nothing changes either way.

```
1>------ Build started: Project: TestAgent, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
1>     Creating library Win32\Debug\TestAgent.lib and object Win32\Debug\TestAgent.exp
1>Registrar.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: long __thiscall StudentManager::Register(class ATL::CStringT<unsigned short,class StrTraitMFC<unsigned short,class ATL::ChTraitsCRT<unsigned short> > > const &,class ATL::CStringT<unsigned short,class StrTraitMFC<unsigned short,class ATL::ChTraitsCRT<unsigned short> > > const &,class ATL::CStringT<unsigned short,class StrTraitMFC<unsigned short,class ATL::ChTraitsCRT<unsigned short> > > const &,class ATL::CStringT<unsigned short,class StrTraitMFC<unsigned short,class ATL::ChTraitsCRT<unsigned short> > > const &,class ATL::CStringT<unsigned short,class StrTraitMFC<unsigned short,class ATL::ChTraitsCRT<unsigned short> > > const &,class ATL::CStringT<unsigned short,class StrTraitMFC<unsigned short,class ATL::ChTraitsCRT<unsigned short> > > const &)" (?Register@StudentManager@@QAEJABV?$CStringT@GV?$StrTraitMFC@GV?$ChTraitsCRT@G@ATL@@@@@ATL@@00000@Z) referenced in function "public: void __thiscall Registrar::PopulateClasses(struct HWND__ *)" (?PopulateClasses@Registrar@@QAEXPAUHWND__@@@Z)
1>TestCase1.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: long __thiscall StudentManager::Register(class ATL::CStringT<unsigned short,class StrTraitMFC<unsigned short,class ATL::ChTraitsCRT<unsigned short> > > const &,class ATL::CStringT<unsigned short,class StrTraitMFC<unsigned short,class ATL::ChTraitsCRT<unsigned short> > > const &,class ATL::CStringT<unsigned short,class StrTraitMFC<unsigned short,class ATL::ChTraitsCRT<unsigned short> > > const &,class ATL::CStringT<unsigned short,class StrTraitMFC<unsigned short,class ATL::ChTraitsCRT<unsigned short> > > const &,class ATL::CStringT<unsigned short,class StrTraitMFC<unsigned short,class ATL::ChTraitsCRT<unsigned short> > > const &,class ATL::CStringT<unsigned short,class StrTraitMFC<unsigned short,class ATL::ChTraitsCRT<unsigned short> > > const &)" (?Register@StudentManager@@QAEJABV?$CStringT@GV?$StrTraitMFC@GV?$ChTraitsCRT@G@ATL@@@@@ATL@@00000@Z)
1>Registrar.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: long __thiscall SectionManager::Register(class ATL::CStringT<unsigned short,class StrTraitMFC<unsigned short,class ATL::ChTraitsCRT<unsigned short> > > const &,class ATL::CStringT<unsigned short,class StrTraitMFC<unsigned short,class ATL::ChTraitsCRT<unsigned short> > > const &,class ATL::CStringT<unsigned short,class StrTraitMFC<unsigned short,class ATL::ChTraitsCRT<unsigned short> > > const &,class ATL::CStringT<unsigned short,class StrTraitMFC<unsigned short,class ATL::ChTraitsCRT<unsigned short> > > const &,class ATL::CStringT<unsigned short,class StrTraitMFC<unsigned short,class ATL::ChTraitsCRT<unsigned short> > > const &,class ATL::CStringT<unsigned short,class StrTraitMFC<unsigned short,class ATL::ChTraitsCRT<unsigned short> > > const &,class ATL::CStringT<unsigned short,class StrTraitMFC<unsigned short,class ATL::ChTraitsCRT<unsigned short> > > const &)" (?Register@SectionManager@@QAEJABV?$CStringT@GV?$StrTraitMFC@GV?$ChTraitsCRT@G@ATL@@@@@ATL@@000000@Z) referenced in function "public: void __thiscall Registrar::PopulateClasses(struct HWND__ *)" (?PopulateClasses@Registrar@@QAEXPAUHWND__@@@Z)
1>TestCase1.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: long __thiscall SectionManager::Register(class ATL::CStringT<unsigned short,class StrTraitMFC<unsigned short,class ATL::ChTraitsCRT<unsigned short> > > const &,class ATL::CStringT<unsigned short,class StrTraitMFC<unsigned short,class ATL::ChTraitsCRT<unsigned short> > > const &,class ATL::CStringT<unsigned short,class StrTraitMFC<unsigned short,class ATL::ChTraitsCRT<unsigned short> > > const &,class ATL::CStringT<unsigned short,class StrTraitMFC<unsigned short,class ATL::ChTraitsCRT<unsigned short> > > const &,class ATL::CStringT<unsigned short,class StrTraitMFC<unsigned short,class ATL::ChTraitsCRT<unsigned short> > > const &,class ATL::CStringT<unsigned short,class StrTraitMFC<unsigned short,class ATL::ChTraitsCRT<unsigned short> > > const &,class ATL::CStringT<unsigned short,class StrTraitMFC<unsigned short,class ATL::ChTraitsCRT<unsigned short> > > const &)" (?Register@SectionManager@@QAEJABV?$CStringT@GV?$StrTraitMFC@GV?$ChTraitsCRT@G@ATL@@@@@ATL@@000000@Z)
1>TeacherSectionManager.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "private: static class ATL::CStringT<unsigned short,class StrTraitMFC<unsigned short,class ATL::ChTraitsCRT<unsigned short> > > Registration::m_strServiceBaseUrl" (?m_strServiceBaseUrl@Registration@@0V?$CStringT@GV?$StrTraitMFC@GV?$ChTraitsCRT@G@ATL@@@@@ATL@@A)
1>Win32\Debug\TestAgent.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 3 unresolved externals
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

Comment: _Also, what does setting project dependencies do exactly?_ It just sets your project build order. If Project A depends on Project B, Project B will always be built first.

Comment: Put both your projects in the same solution file, then add the static library reference to the executable project's properties by going to the executable project's Properties Pages -> Common Properties -> Add New Reference.

Comment: Or make sure your project is set to "Link dependent libraries". I doing so, any project the current one is dependent on that produces a .lib output (either by DLL import library or static lib) will auto-link the dependency for you.

Answer (score 0):

See [this blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vcblog/archive/2010/05/03/flexible-project-to-project-references.aspx) for a good overview.
What it does exactly is more powerful than just cause it to be built first.  It also knows just where it put the library, so you do not have to fill your library-path list with hard coded places to look, which is especially annoying when the path is different for each configuration.

Make sure what you mean by "set to depend on" is the new project-to-project references, *not* the solution level Build Order/Build Dependencies dialog box.

You can turn on verbose output in linking, to see what inputs are actually resolved.  In this case, looking at the logged command line is enough.  If that shows the desired lib is included, then it's probably a matter of compiler options that affect the name mangling, or sometimes evil #define macros that change the actual name of the symbol without you knowing.